# Memory table's primary key must be HASH, why?

Tags: mysql, memory-table

I want to use a memory table as a set of queues.

So, there'll be a memory table with int column a and b.
with queries like:
SELECT b FROM table WHERE a=? ORDER BY b DESC LIMIT 1000

I tried this:

```
create table `test_table` (
    `a` int(11) not null,
    `b` int(11) not null,
    primary key (`a`,`b`) using btree
) engine=memory
```

but the primary key is still HASH:

```
show index from `test_table`

Table       Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment
----------  ----------  --------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------
test_table           0  PRIMARY              1  a            (NULL)          (NULL)    (NULL)  (NULL)          HASH
test_table           0  PRIMARY              2  b            (NULL)               0    (NULL)  (NULL)          HASH
```

1. Does that means, I need to create another key(`a`) for such queries?
2. Why primary key can not be a BTREE index? What's the difference if I change the primary key to just a regular key?

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the index type by using alter query.

```
ALTER TABLE test_table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (a,b);
```

OR Using below create query,

`create table test_table (a int(11) not null,b int(11) not null,primary key USING BTREE(a,b)) engine=memory`

For further details about memory engine, please go through below link.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html